# Import JSON in R using API as dataframe

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to import data in R using api link.

Here is my API link: [Link](https://malariaapitracker.com/web/api/http/http.php?id=21)

Here is glimpse of data

```
{"DataID":"311","Question":"Health facility code","Answer":"2555","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"311","Question":"Health facility code","Answer":"2555","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"310","Question":"Disease severityy","Answer":"UM,VM","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"310","Question":"Disease severityy","Answer":"UM,VM","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"309","Question":"Type of malariaa","Answer":"PF,PV","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"309","Question":"Type of malariaa","Answer":"PF,PV","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"308","Question":"Mode of diagnosisss","Answer":"RDT","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"308","Question":"Mode of diagnosisss","Answer":"RDT","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"307","Question":"Patient age","Answer":"50","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"307","Question":"Patient age","Answer":"50","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:47 pm"}{"DataID":"306","Question":"Patient sex","Answer":"Male","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:46 pm"}{"DataID":"306","Question":"Patient sex","Answer":"Male","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:46 pm"}{"DataID":"305","Question":"Patient residence code","Answer":"Union","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:46 pm"}{"DataID":"305","Question":"Patient residence code","Answer":"Union","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"7701049","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:46 pm"}{"DataID":"304","Question":"Health facility code","Answer":"2555","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"303","Question":"Disease severityy","Answer":"UM,SM","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"302","Question":"Type of malariaa","Answer":"PF,Mixed","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"301","Question":"Mode of diagnosisss","Answer":"Microscopy","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"300","Question":"Patient age","Answer":"50","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"299","Question":"Patient sex","Answer":"Female","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"298","Question":"Patient residence code","Answer":"Union","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"3278221","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:44 pm"}{"DataID":"293","Question":"Health facility code","Answer":"4500","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"292","Question":"Disease severityy","Answer":"UM,SM","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"291","Question":"Type of malariaa","Answer":"PF,Mixed","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"290","Question":"Mode of diagnosisss","Answer":"RDT","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"289","Question":"Patient age","Answer":"40","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"288","Question":"Patient sex","Answer":"Male","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"287","Question":"Patient residence code","Answer":"Union","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"4169191","Date":"2022-01-07, 2:15 pm"}{"DataID":"274","Question":"Health facility code","Answer":"222","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"273","Question":"Disease severityy","Answer":"UM,SM","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"272","Question":"Type of malariaa","Answer":"PF,PV","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"271","Question":"Mode of diagnosisss","Answer":"RDT","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"270","Question":"Patient age","Answer":"21","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"269","Question":"Patient sex","Answer":"Male","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"268","Question":"Patient residence code","Answer":"Union","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"2926181","Date":"2021-12-11, 3:30 am"}{"DataID":"267","Question":"Health facility code","Answer":"1250","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}{"DataID":"266","Question":"Disease severityy","Answer":"UM,VM","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}{"DataID":"265","Question":"Type of malariaa","Answer":"PV,Mixed","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}{"DataID":"264","Question":"Mode of diagnosisss","Answer":"Microscopy","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}{"DataID":"263","Question":"Patient age","Answer":"50","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}{"DataID":"262","Question":"Patient sex","Answer":"Female","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}{"DataID":"261","Question":"Patient residence code","Answer":"Union","Status":"Approved","Verify_code":"8883179","Date":"2021-12-07, 3:01 pm"}
```

Now, I want to import this data using api link as dataframe in R.

Answer (score 2):

```
lnk <- readLines('https://malariaapitracker.com/web/api/http/http.php?id=21')
jsonlite::fromJSON(sprintf('[%s]', gsub('}{', '},{', lnk, fixed = TRUE)))

   DataID               Question     Answer   Status Verify_code                Date
1     311   Health facility code       2555 Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
2     311   Health facility code       2555 Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
3     310      Disease severityy      UM,VM Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
4     310      Disease severityy      UM,VM Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
5     309       Type of malariaa      PF,PV Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
6     309       Type of malariaa      PF,PV Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
7     308    Mode of diagnosisss        RDT Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
8     308    Mode of diagnosisss        RDT Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
9     307            Patient age         50 Approved     7701049 2022-01-07, 2:47 pm
:
:
:
```

Comment: It shows error on my side.
Error: parse error: invalid object key (must be a string)
                                     [{] [    "Date": "2021-12-07, 3:0
                     (right here) ------^